# Is %timeit applied to a function or reference via parameters in command line?

Tags: python, timeit

I'm following a guide that suggests running `%timeit following` where `following` is a defined function.

I've tried using `import timeit` but for some reason `%timeit` does not run. I get a syntax error so clearly I'm not using it correctly. I've made a brief search that yielded pages on `timeit` library but this confuses me even more in terms of usage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect that you are confusing `%timeit` with `timeit`:

- [`%timeit`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) is an IPython "magic" command that will only work within an IPython shell session. Example useage would be:

  ```
  In [1]: %timeit myfunc()
  ```
- `timeit`is a standard Python module - you can `import timeit` in your script, and use `timeit.timeit("expression")` etc. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)  for full details.

---

Here is an example showing one way you could use `timeit.timeit` from within an IPython session:

```
In [2]: def foo(): pass

In [3]: import timeit

In [4]: timeit.timeit("foo()", setup="from __main__ import foo", number=10000)
Out[4]: 0.004509925842285156
```

In this case, our function `foo` is defined within the global namespace of the IPython session, so we import it from `__main__`. If it was defined in some external module then it would be necessary to modify the `import` statement to reflect this, e.g.:

```
In [5]: timeit.timeit("pow(10, 3)", setup="from math import pow", number=10000)
Out[5]: 0.00642085075378418
```

Here I'm importing the `pow` function from the `math` module.

Comment: I see, do they both do the same thing in effect?

Comment: `%timeit` is essentially just a more convenient way to call `timeit.timeit` from within an IPython session.

Comment: I had a look at the documentation, thank you. I gathered the best command to run was: timeit.timeit('following()', number=10000). Why is this not correct?

Comment: Your `following` function is not defined within the expression you are passing to `timeit`. To give `timeit` access to functions that you have defined yourself, you can pass a `setup=` argument, e.g. `timeit.timeit("following()", setup="from mymodule import following")`. There is an example at the bottom of the documentation page I linked to.

Comment: i tried using the above code as suggested but no luck. I got Name errors stating it was not defined. I even tried changing _mymodule_ to __main__ but it didn't like that either stating that a certain parameter was not found. Whats the best way for me to find out why this is wrong?

Comment: It could be that your `import` statement is invalid. In order for `from mymodule import following` to work, `mymodule` must either be a module within your Python path or a package within the current module.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had been inputting the command wrong.

Answer (score 3):

To try to reproduce `%timeit` from IPython's magic with `timeit` try this:

```
timeit.Timer(my_function).repeat(3, 1000)
```

%timeit takes the best of 3 count with n executions, where n is chosen internally (so 1000 in repeat() might not be a good choice)

[reference](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/interactive/magics.html?highlight=timeit#magic-timeit):

> -n N: execute the given statement N times in a loop. If this value is not given, a fitting value is chosen.
>
> -r R: repeat the loop iteration R times and take the best result. Default: 3

Comment: Hi, I tried running this but i keep getting a NameError, `following` not found. any ideas?